# Korean word for (presentation) slides

Tags: vocabulary

I think PowerPoint presentation slides are referred to as "창표" or "장표." However, I can't find it in the dictionary.

What's the Korean word I'm thinking of?

---

**update: context**

I have heard this term many times while working at multiple Korean offices. I have even used the term myself, and everyone knew what I was talking about.

The word is a drop-in replacement for (PowerPoint presentation) "slide." As in:

- "I will have the slides ready by tomorrow."
- "Please take a look at the last slide."

I could not find it in any (Korean-English) dictionaries, so I was wondering if my spelling was wrong, it was the combination and shortening of two or more words, or it was office slang.

Comment: "PowerPoint" is usually called "파워포인트" or "피피티", and "slide" is "슬라이드". Maybe you are thinking of "발표자료"? I never heard of "장표".

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy No need o delete the question just to have 100% answer rate which is never a big deal, instead if Memming posts the same comment as an answer and then OP can accpt it as an answer.

Comment: @Memming when I type '장표' in google, one of the auto-suggestions is '장표 ppt'... Make of that what you will!

Comment: It seems to be a slang used in business companies. It's good to avoid using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The word I was looking for was "[장표](http://m.krdic.naver.com/entry/32395100/)."**

Etymology: (according to native Korean speaker, the usage of 장표 has recently changed)

> 장표가 원래는 [그 사람] 말처럼 ledger 이긴 했어 근데 현대들어오면서 종이 두루마리에 여러장 엮어서 프리젠테이션 하는게 생겼는데
>   그걸 장표라고 했거든. 그러다 컴퓨터가 쓰이면서 ppt문서를 계속해서 장표라고 부르게된거야.

Source: Native Korean

[image]

Comment: @Rathony: FYI I already edited out the beginning of that quote, which started quite condescendingly and did not add much to the answer (hence no screen capture).

Comment: I couldn't care less about what he said. You need to note that the dictionary link in the capture and your answer has nothing to do with what that guy meant. The definition is completely different from what "장표" means in his explanation.

Comment: The word is available on the main web based naver online dictionary, at http://dic.naver.com/search.nhn?dicQuery=%EC%9E%A5%ED%91%9C&query=%EC%9E%A5%ED%91%9C&target=dic&ie=utf8&query_utf=&isOnlyViewEE=albeit it's the same one from the mobile version

Answer (score 2):

The reason you couldn't find what "[장표](http://alldic.daum.net/search.do?q=%EC%9E%A5%ED%91%9C)" means in the dictionary was it is not defined to mean a slide in presentation material in any dictionary. I have checked all the dictionaries available on-line and there is no definition for a slide, even in [국립국어원 표준국어대사전](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1940/korean-word-for-presentation-slides).

As I commented, I heard the word used in a banking or financial context to mean a page on a ledger, a book, or an excel sheet, but I have never heard it used in presentation context.

I tried to Google "프리젠테이션 장표" and "프리젠테이션 슬라이드", the former has 783 hits and the latter has 20,700 results, which shows the former is far less used than the latter.

> I will have the slides ready by tomorrow.

내일까지 **프레젠테이션 자료들**을 준비하겠습니다. vs 내일까지 **장표들**을 준비하겠습니다.

> Please take a look at the last slide.

마지막쪽 **슬라이드**를 봐주세요. vs 마지막쪽 **장표**를 봐주세요.

If you use 장표 in place of bolded parts in the above translation, they will sound very weird, especially for those who have never heard of 장표, especially in presentation context.

Conclusion: If "장표" is broadly used to mean a slide, it would have been listed in the dictionaries that I looked up. There is no single dictionary that lists it to mean a slide. You had better not use it when 슬라이드 can mean perfectly well a slide.